# Will spinning DC motor in space generate infinite energy?

Tags: electricity, energy-conservation, perpetual-motion

If I take a DC motor far in space and spin it, will it continue to spin forever and generate infinite electrical energy?

If so, then won't it violate law of conservation of energy?

Comment: Gravity is unrelated to the working of a DC motor,  it will work the same way in space than on Earth.

Comment: In general, a perpetual motion machine doesn't work

Comment: Why would you think it would work? And what does being in space have to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make any object spin, whether a motor or a lump of rock, you have to do work on it. The work you do on the object goes into its rotational kinetic energy.

Once an object is spinning it can slow down only by doing work on its surroundings. The work the object does on its surroundings comes from the rotational kinetic energy of the object.

In the specific case of the motor a spinning motor acts as a generator and generates an EMF called the [back EMF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter-electromotive_force). If you connect the electrical connectors of the motor to a load the back EMF will produce a current through the load and dissipate energy as a result. The energy comes from the rotational kinetic energy of the motor so it will slow down.

However if you do not connect a load to the motor then no current will flow and no energy will be dissipated. Assuming there are no frictional losses the motor will spin forever. 
This doesn't violate conservation of energy because no energy is being extracted from the motor. The motor does generate a voltage, but unless some current flows the voltage doesn't result in any work being done.

Answer (score 0):

it will spin only until its total kinetic energy remains above zero. The motor has a back emf induced on it due to Lenz's law. If you leave a constant spinning armature of the motor in space suspended in a magnetic field, then the back emf induced will cause a current to flow in a direction such that the motion is resisted, and as a result the kinetic energy drops to zero. conservation of energy is not violated in this case as the rotational kinetic energy of the motor is transferred to the energy of electrons in the armature of the motor. that is why a motor running with constant speed needs a source of emf, or otherwise the back emf will stop the motor.

Comment: Your argument applies only if the external circuit is left connected. If you disconnect the external circuit no energy will be dissipated and (ignoring friction) the motor will spin forever.

Comment: @JohnRennie it won't even then. When the armature is at a configuration where the rate of change of flux is maximum, then there will be an induced potential difference at the ends. Now some rotational energy will be lost in this. Secondly, when the rate of change of flux thru the armature dies down, then the induced potential difference at the ends will cause current to flow through the circuit and going back to normal to initial case but with a reduced rotational kinetic energy now. This process will continue over and over until the motor stops.

Comment: @JohnRennie the current due to induced emf after every minimum of rate of change of flux will keep on dissipating the energy in addition to due to generation of back emf. Apologies for the poor explanation